# API first or not

Tags: api, user-experience

I've a global question about the steps to develop an app as I'm sorry, but I'm not a developper.
I'm working in a start up which wants to develop a web application.
We have a fullstack developper working with us on the development of the API at the moment.
We're now looking for working with a frontend team and an UX/UI team to help us as we have a short time to build the app.
We thought that the first step would be to create the different layouts so that the frontend dev team can start coding while our fullstack dev is coding the API.
But the frontend lead dev says that they can't start until they have the API finished with the documentation.
Is that exact ? What would be the best strategy ? API first ? Or front ? Or both at the same time ?

Answer (score 1):

This is too general but no, you should definitely not wait to have the API finished to start with the front-end. Even less in the context of an Startup.

You want to have feedback from customers ASAP, it makes no sense to leave front-end to the last minute.

From the front-end side you might want to have your views decoupled from the data format on the API side, at least at the beginning. Of course you'll have some rework on the front-end once the APIs are finished but as a trade-off to that, you'll get something to show and feedback sooner.
I don't want to get too technical because you said you are not a developer, but you should try to convince your coworkers to find a way to work in the views and in the API at the same time, accepting some rework at the end.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply @R44. I understand and I agree with your point of view as maybe the best practice would be to wait for the API to be finished, but we don't have the time to wait the API to be finished

Comment: Sorry @Hippipers, maybe I expressed myself wrong, but I was saying totally the opposite. I don't think you should wait the API to be finished

Comment: No worries @R44, that's my fault I expressed myself wrong. Thanks again for taking the time to answer me

Comment: I agree with @R44. Do not wait to the API to be finished to advance the frontend part. Moreover, try create a safety net including automated API test in your CI/CD pipelines. [Here](https://www.redsauce.net/blog/en/back-or-front-functional-test) you can find some tips about frontend and API tests.